# Requst.Form empty on server not on localhost

Tags: iis, request.form

Our partner is posting a notifikation to our server. When using Request.Form on the server there are no keys and not data at all.

When doing the same thing on localhost all data are populated just fine.

Were using IIS8.5 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Could you see the data when you trace request with fiddler ?

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by an http to an https redirection. When disabling this rule in an subdirectory it all worked.